# kotlin - prevent lambda from capturing a view accessed using kotlin synthetics

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, kotlin-android-extensions, findviewbyid

I use the Kotlin Android Extensions plugin for accessing views from XML. If I understand that properly, the synthetic properties generated for the views are nullable, to be more precise - their type is `View!`, meaning that they can be treated as non-null in Kotlin, but actually they can still be null because under the hood `findViewById` is called, which is from Java, so Kotlin can't ensure null-safety. This is okay because we can use the `?.` operator.

The problem comes when you need to use these in a lambda because the null value gets captured and you never get the chance to handle the non-null value.

See these two snippets.
In the moment these are executed, `view1` is non null, but `view2` is null:

```
//this one crashes
view1.setOnClickListener {
    view2.doStuff()
}
//this one works
view1.setOnClickListener {
    findViewById<View>(R.id.view2).doStuff()
}
```

What happens in the first case is that when the line is executed, `view2` is null and the lambda captures it as null. So even if `view2` is not null anymore when the lambda runs (`view1` was clicked), the app crashes.

In the second case, the lambda doesn't capture anything, so even though `view2` is null at first, it is retrieved again every time the lambda runs (`view1` is clicked).

**So the question is: How can I use the synthetic property in lambdas, without the initial value being captured?**

Thank you!